# I can't seem to deploy a model-serving endpoint in DataBricks from a finetuned model in DBFS

Tags: databricks, huggingface-transformers, mlflow

I have finetuned a GPT-2 model within databricks and saved the model and tokenizer into DBFS. I am trying to log, register, and deploy that model to an endpoint, which I am not sure is currently possible at the moment. I have followed along with the examples provided [here](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-ml-examples/blob/master/llm-models/mpt/mpt-7b/02_mlflow_logging_inference.py), [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/mlflow/models.html), [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/model-serving/llm-optimized-model-serving.html), [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/model-serving/model-serving-intro.html), and [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/model-serving/create-manage-serving-endpoints.html#notebook-examples), and while the examples work for me, I haven't been able to swap out the foundation models used with a finetuned model of my own. Here is some code that **very closely** approximates my code for logging and registering the model:

```
# Define PythonModel to log with mlflow.pyfunc.log_model
class GPT(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
    def load_context(self, context):
        """
        This method initializes the tokenizer and language model.
        """
        self.tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained(snapshot_location)

        config = GPT2Config.from_pretrained(snapshot_location)

        self.model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained(snapshot_location, config=config)

        self.model.to(device='cuda')

        self.model.eval()

    def predict(self, model_input):
        """
        This method generates prediction for the given input.
        """
        generated_text = []
        for index, row in model_input.iterrows():
            prompt = row["prompt"]
            temperature=model_input.get("temperature", [0.7])[0]
            max_new_tokens=model_input.get("max_new_tokens", [100])[0]
            
            full_prompt = prompt
            encoded_input = self.tokenizer.encode(full_prompt, return_tensors="pt").to('cuda')
            output = self.model.generate(encoded_input, 
                                        temperature=temperature,
                                        max_new_tokens=max_new_tokens)
            prompt_length = len(encoded_input[0])
            generated_text.append(self.tokenizer.batch_decode(output[:,prompt_length:], skip_special_tokens=True))
        return pd.Series(generated_text)


# Define input and output schema
input_schema = Schema([
    ColSpec(DataType.string, "prompt"), 
    ColSpec(DataType.double, "temperature", optional=False), 
    ColSpec(DataType.integer, "max_new_tokens", optional=False)
    ])
output_schema = Schema([ColSpec(DataType.string, 'output')])
signature = ModelSignature(inputs=input_schema, outputs=output_schema)

# Define input example
input_example=pd.DataFrame({
            "prompt":["$PROMPT"], 
            "temperature": [0.7],
            "max_new_tokens": [100]
            })

# Log the model with its details such as artifacts, pip requirements and input example
torch_version = torch.__version__.split("+")[0]
with mlflow.start_run() as run:  
    mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(
        "model",
        python_model=GPT(),
        artifacts={'repository' : snapshot_location},
        pip_requirements=[f"torch=={torch_version}", 
                          f"transformers=={transformers.__version__}", 
                          f"accelerate=={accelerate.__version__}", "einops", "sentencepiece"],
        input_example=input_example,
        signature=signature
    )

mlflow.set_registry_uri("databricks-uc")

registered_name = "models.default.gpt" # Note that the UC model name follows the pattern <catalog_name>.<schema_name>.<model_name>, corresponding to the catalog, schema, and registered model name

# Register model in MLflow Model Registry
result = mlflow.register_model(
    "runs:/"+run.info.run_id+"/model",
    name=registered_name,
    await_registration_for=1000,
)

client = MlflowClient(registry_uri="databricks-uc")

# Choose the right model version registered in the above cell.
client.set_registered_model_alias(name=registered_name, alias="GPT_model", version=result.version)
```

I can sucessfully log and register the model just fine, the issues arise when I try to prompt the model within a notebook or set up a model serving endpoint. As you can tell, I have not deviated much from the provided tutorials, but I believe everything hinges on where the `snapshot_location` variable points to. I have tried pointing it at a dbfs file path, only to get the error while trying to serve the model `An error occurred while loading the model. Repo id must be in the form 'repo_name' or 'namespace/repo_name': '/dbfs/$FILEPATH'. Use 'repo_type' argument if needed..` in the service logs. I then tried the code:

```
snapshot_location = os.path.expanduser("~/gpt/output")
os.makedirs(snapshot_location, exist_ok=True)
```

which gave me the error `HFValidationError: Repo id must be in the form 'repo_name' or 'namespace/repo_name': '/root/gpt/output'. Use 'repo_type' argument if needed.` while trying to prompt the model within a notebook.

My question is, is there a way to somehow get the `repo_type` flag somewhere in there? If I can't save the model in DBFS, should I be saving the model in an S3 bucket? Googling the error led me to a lot of github comments about including the full file path, but I am not sure how applicable that is to my problem. I am going to try to move the files from DBFS onto the local disk, and try and register the model from there. Am I going about this the right way though? Is the issue not with the location but with my logging and registration code? Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.